# JavaFX css styles not working - Unknown property + Resource not found

Tags: java, css, javafx

I am getting the warning "Unknown property" for the following code, located in my css/styles.css file:

```
.root {
    -fx-background-color: #000000;
}
```

I do have jfxrt.jar in my JRE System Library, and JavaFX works fine otherwise.

When I run the program, the custom style does not appear at all on the view I am trying to apply it to.

The following is in the view file:

```
Scene scene = new Scene(pane);
scene.getStylesheets().add("css/styles.css");
stage.setScene(scene);
```

EDIT:

I am getting the following warning in the console:

> WARNING: Resource "css/styles.css" not found.

The path for the css file is: `View/css/styles.css`

Path for login view is `View/LoginView.java`

Comment: I've tried your CSS, and I don't get that error... Are you sure you're running what you *think* you're running...?

Comment: How do you mean? When I run it I press the play button (in eclipse). This project is the only one I have open. I run the program as a Java application and the view that pops up is the homepage. I click "Login" button to open login view. I'm expecting the background to be black but it's not. Not sure what I'm doing wrong? :/

Comment: Oh I just realised I'm getting the warning in console that reads "WARNING: Resource css/styles.css not found". So it must be somehow related to the file path? Added some edits above.

Answer (score 5):

I figured it out. I just needed to change

```
scene.getStylesheets().add("css/styles.css");
```

to

```
scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("css/styles.css").toExternalForm());
```